# How to count the number of attributes of a node?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

In XSL, how to count the number of attributes of a node?

For example:

`<a/>` has zero attribute.

`<a foo="1"/>` has one attribute.

`<a foo="1" bar="2"/>` has two attributes.

Answer (score 4):

Simply `count(@*)` for any element.

**XML Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <a b="12" c="13"/>
    <b d="14"/>
</root>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:text>Attribute count for element named "</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;: ', count(@*))"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Text Output**

```
Attribute count for element named "root": 0
Attribute count for element named "a": 2
Attribute count for element named "b": 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:value-of select="count(@*)"/>
</xsl:tempate>
```